# NullException on onPostExecute void

Tags: java, android, download, android-asynctask

I'm trying to finish my DownloadFile class, which is a sub-class of AsyncTask.
So this is the code of the class:

```
private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
            URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
            urlc.connect();
            int fileLength = urlc.getContentLength();
            InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath().concat("data/com.markosoft.maturko/databases/proba.mp3"));
            byte Data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while((count=is.read(Data))!=-1)
            {
                total+=count;
                publishProgress((int)total * 100 / fileLength);
                os.write(Data,0,count);
            }
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            is.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)
    {
        dl.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused)
    {
        dl.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Podaci uspešno preuzeti", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I'm getting a NullPointerException error and also "thread exiting with uncaught exception" error. This error occured when I've added the Toast call that shows that the download has finished, but as far as I know onPostExecute is executed on the UI thread so I don't see the problem. Also another thing that troubles me is that the download doesn't finish, or rather doesn't start at all. When I call the function that calls DownloadFile.execute(link) function the onPostExecute function activates instantly... Thanks for the help

EDIT: dl is a ProgressDialog that is initialized before dlf.execute(link) is called so that shouldn't be the cause of NullPointerException...
EDIT: Here's the requested LogCat log:

```
03-22 19:56:51.119: W/dalvikvm(546): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
03-22 19:56:51.140: E/AndroidRuntime(546): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 19:56:51.140: E/AndroidRuntime(546): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 19:56:51.140: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:92)
03-22 19:56:51.140: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:233)
03-22 19:56:51.140: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at com.markosoft.maturko.Upit$DownloadFile.onPostExecute(Upit.java:68)
03-22 19:56:51.140: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at com.markosoft.maturko.Upit$DownloadFile.onPostExecute(Upit.java:1)
03-22 19:56:51.140: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
03-22 19:56:51.140: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
03-22 19:56:51.140: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
03-22 19:56:51.140: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-22 19:56:51.140: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-22 19:56:51.140: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
03-22 19:56:51.140: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 19:56:51.140: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-22 19:56:51.140: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-22 19:56:51.140: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-22 19:56:51.140: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

or if you'd rather look at it in Notepad++ here's the link:
[Log](http://www.sendspace.com/file/2gs2sk)

Comment: Please post all of your Logcat errors and where do you define `dl`?

Comment: ok try to show toast as :`Toast.makeText(Your_Current_Fragment.this.getActivity(), "Podaci uspešno preuzeti", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: I don't think you can call `getActivity()` on an AsyncTask can you? I could be wrong...

Comment: @TheCapn is right, that's why I got the fatal exception. However why my DownloadFile class doesn't download a file is still unanswered :(

Comment: Is this class inside a `DialogFragment`?  If so, is `dl` the dialog that is returned as part of the `DialogFragment`?

Comment: @MCeley they're both subclasses inside DialogFragment. But dl is part of the mentioned DialogFragment field and DownloadFile is initialized within a function of the DialogFragment. I hope you can understand what I've written.

Comment: Can you post your `onCreateDialog` function of your `DialogFragment`?

Comment: Will post it in 5 minutes.
EDIT: I'll post my entire class in another question, so you can see everything.

Comment: Keep it in this question since you're still in need of an answer.  No need to create a new question just to post code that's relevant to this one.

Comment: I've already did [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578513/asynctask-not-executing-download)
This resolved my NullPointerException error. So I hope the next one will resolve the AsyncTask not working properly.

Comment: If an answer here was able to answer your question then be sure to mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark under the voting arrows.  If an answer here didn't meet your needs then it would be beneficial to others if you posted an answer with the solution and marked it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. Look at the topic under heading **The 4 steps**.

You are getting NullPointerException for the Toast. If you calling asynctask from say MainActivity then

Try

```
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Podaci uspešno preuzeti", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Your should pass activity context,your text and duration as parameters to makeText.

```
                                   OR
```

As suggested by Eng.Fouad your dl is null.

Comment: No, it is not. It's `unused`.

Comment: Check the highlighted part of the answer

Comment: A `NullPointerException` is raised whenever you are invoking an instance method or accessing an instance field on a reference variable that refers (points) to null. The result passed is not used at all.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is because `dl` is `null`, so on first call to `onProgressUpdate()`, a `NullPointerException` is thrown and catched by the catch-bock in `doInBackground()`.

Next, `onPostExecute()` is invoked and `NullPointerException` is thrown again, but this time it is propagated to the android main launcher of the application.

Comment: I forgot to say that dl is initialized (it's a ProgressDialog) before the dlf is executed. It's certainly not null, but what is I cannot determine :(

Comment: @user2200454 Try `Log.d("dl", dl == null)` at the first line of `doInBackground()`.

Comment: Why not post a stack trace? It should be present in the output provided by "adb logcat"

Comment: I thought about taking a screenshot but since I'm new, I'll have to copy the text. I'll post it in the original problem. Thanks