# AsyncTask not executing download

Tags: java, android, download, android-asynctask

Like I wrote in my former question, the subclass of AsyncTask I wrote doesn't download file as intended.

```
public class Upit extends DialogFragment {

    public ProgressDialog dl;

    private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
                URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
                urlc.connect();
                int fileLength = urlc.getContentLength();
                InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(
                        Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                                .concat("data/com.markosoft.maturko/databases/proba.mp3"));
                byte Data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                int count;
                while ((count = is.read(Data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress((int) total * 100 / fileLength);
                    os.write(Data, 0, count);
                }
                os.flush();
                os.close();
                is.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR_TAG", e.getMessage());
                return "Podaci neuspešno preuzeti";
            }
            return "Podaci uspešno preuzeti";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
            dl.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(dl.getContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dl.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanteState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        b.setMessage(R.string.upit_poruka)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.upit_da, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if (Provera()) {
                            upd(getActivity());
                        }
                        Izadji();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.upit_ne, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Izadji();
                    }
                });
        return b.create();
    }

    protected void Izadji() {
        this.dismiss();
    }

    protected boolean Provera() {
        return true;
    }

    public void upd(Context context) {
        dl = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dl.setMessage("Preuzimanje najnovijih podataka...");
        dl.setIndeterminate(false);
        dl.setMax(100);
        dl.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dl.setCancelable(true);
        dl.show();
        DownloadFile dlf = new DownloadFile();
        dlf.execute("http://podcasts.aolcdn.com/massively/podcasts/03-19-13-massively-E241.mp3");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

The problem is most likely in the path of the file. BTW, I've asked for permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: try opening the url in the browser. I tried opening in browser the url is fine.

Comment: The link I'm downloading is fine. I've downloaded it both on my PC and my iPhone, so I guess it's still available on :80

Comment: Try switching to [`HttpURLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) if your resource is out on the web.

Comment: Are you not getting an error?  Many of these methods throw Exceptions, are you not getting any?  Have you tried adding logging to your class to view some of your variables?  For example, I'd want to know the values of `url` and `fileLength`.

Comment: My bad, now that I've added logging the Exception e, it revealed that I didn't create the file I intended to write to. Thanks for the help.

Comment: you are not creating the a path properly to store the file.

Comment: Ironically, it seems I'm missing a forward slash ('/') at the beginning of the concatenated string. I'll post if that solves the problem. I can't believe that it took me 2 hours to notice -.-

Comment: That solved the pathing error, but I'm getting the "EACCESS (Permission denied)" error even though I've added android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE . Anybody sees the problem now?